# My program cannot find my shared library during execution

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

My program cannot find my shared library during execution.
That's how I compiled everything:

```
//shared library fct
g++ -c -fpic fct.cpp
g++ -shared fct.o -o libfct.so

//my program
g++ main.cpp -L/home/user/shared_library/ -lfct -I/home/user/shared_library/ -o main
```

When I tried to run the program, it gives me this error message:

```
./main: error while loading shared libraries: libfct.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

here's my source files:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "fct.h"

int main()
{
   fct();

   return 0;
}
```

fct.h:

```
#ifndef FCT_HEADER_INCLUDED
#define FCT_HEADER_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>

void fct();

#endif
```

fct.cpp:

```
#include "fct.h"

void fct()
{
    std::cout << "fct() was called!\n";
}
```

Comment: I am assuming you have double checked that fctlib.so is in /home/user/shared_library, right?

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi Yes. The library file was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shared library path is needed twice, both at compile time and runtime. Passing the library path to the compiler does not guarantee that the linker will be able to find it. For a temporary solution, you can add `home/user/shared_library` to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable (on Linux & macOS). For a more permanent solution, you should install it in a directory on the [default dynamic linker search path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367600/what-is-the-order-that-linuxs-dynamic-linker-searches-paths-in).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I would have to inform the path at runtime also.